# Determining length of gzipped file in custom RecordReader

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have written a custom record reader to read both text and gzipped files in Hadoop as I have a special requirement of having the complete file data as the value and the file name of the key. The source is as follows:

```
public class WholeFileRecordReader extends RecordReader<Text, BytesWritable> {

    private CompressionCodecFactory compressionCodecs = null;
    private FileSplit fileSplit;
    private Configuration conf;
    private InputStream in;
    private Text key = new Text("");
    private BytesWritable value = new BytesWritable();
    private boolean processed = false;

    @Override
    public void initialize(InputSplit split, TaskAttemptContext context)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        this.fileSplit = (FileSplit) split;
        this.conf = context.getConfiguration();

        final Path file = fileSplit.getPath();
        compressionCodecs = new CompressionCodecFactory(conf);

        final CompressionCodec codec = compressionCodecs.getCodec(file);
        System.out.println(codec);
        FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
        in = fs.open(file);

        if (codec != null) {
            in = codec.createInputStream(in);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        if (!processed) {
            byte[] contents = new byte[(int) fileSplit.getLength()];
            Path file = fileSplit.getPath();
            key.set(file.getName());

            try {
                IOUtils.readFully(in, contents, 0, contents.length);
                value.set(contents, 0, contents.length);
            } finally {
                IOUtils.closeStream(in);
            }

            processed = true;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Text getCurrentKey() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return key;
    }

    @Override
    public BytesWritable getCurrentValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public float getProgress() throws IOException {
        return processed ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        // Do nothing
    }

}
```

The problem is that my code is reading incomplete file data. This is probably because I am using the fileSplit (which points to the compressed file) to determine the length of the contents and hence I am getting a smaller value. Therefore this is causing incomplete data to be passed to the Mapper.

Can someone point out how can I get the actual length of the gizipped file data or modify the RecordReader such that it reads the complete data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending over @Chris White's answer, I had to make certain syntactical changes to the code he gave. It's as follows:

```
fileLength = (int) fileSplit.getLength();
compressionCodecs = new CompressionCodecFactory(conf);

final CompressionCodec codec = compressionCodecs.getCodec(file);
FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
in = fs.open(file);

if (codec != null) {
    if (codec instanceof GzipCodec) {
        byte[] len = new byte[4];
        try {
            in.skip(fileLength - 4);
            IOUtils.readFully(in, len, 0, len.length);
            fileLength = (len[3] << 24) | (len[2] << 16) + (len[1] << 8) + len[0];
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
    }

    in = fs.open(file);
    in = codec.createInputStream(in);
}
```

Thanks a lot @Chris White for your inputs. couldn't have done it without you :)

Comment: Hi aa8y, I am using your code to process .gz binary file, but still the length is less than that of the extracted file. Can you please help me? Here is the nexykeyValue function:  public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException, InterruptedException { if (!processed) {byte[] contents = new byte[ (int)fileLength];Path file = fileSplit.getPath();key.set(file.getName());
try{ IOUtils.readFully(in, contents, 0, contents.length);
        value.set(contents, 0, contents.length);}
       finally {
         IOUtils.closeStream(in);}processed = true;return true;} return false;}

Comment: If I print fileLength in the job, for extracted file the length is 2,37,788 while for compress file its 1,71,996.

Comment: This works but are you not doing 2 passes over the data. Isn't there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

For GZip files, you can skip to the last 4 bytes which (according to the spec), should return the original uncompressed file size). There is a note that the value is modulod by 2^32, so be careful if you expect the original file to be larger than this.

- http://www.gzip.org/zlib/rfc-gzip.html

So your initialize method could be amended to something similar to this (untested!):

```
final CompressionCodec codec = compressionCodecs.getCodec(file);
System.out.println(codec);
FileSystem fs = file.getFileSystem(conf);
in = fs.open(file);

length = fileSplit.getLength();
if (codec instanceof GZipCodec) {
  // skip to last 4 bytes
  in.seek(length-4);

  // read size
  length = in.readInt();

  // reset stream position
  in.seek(0);
}
```

Now you should have the actual file length (for an uncompressed and Gzip compressed), which you can use in your nextKeyValue() method.

Comment: `if (codec instance GZipCodec)` Is this valid in Java? And this still extracts the length from the `fileSplit` object which points to the compressed file. I still believe its length would be less than that of the extracted file.

Comment: Sorry `instanceof` should work. And yes, the last 4 bytes of the compressed file indicate the original uncompressed length

Comment: @ChrisWhite would this fit into the record reader without doing a first pass to get the uncompressed data size and second pass to read actual data as in the accepted answer?

Comment: It's not really two passes as you use a skip for the first pass.